# QlikView 12 - Unlinking Objects

Tags: qlikview

I have copied a sheet (and the corresponding objects).
The problem is that the objects are linked. In QlikView 11, if I remember correctly, you could right click on an object and choose 'Unlink'. However, I do not see this function in QlikVIew 12. So, how do you unlink objects in QV 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was taken from a Qlikview 12 module :
[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks - it is correct. Some other thing was the problem with my app.

Answer (score 2):

An extra note on copying objects in QlikView. Not all objects will be copied as linked objects when copying a sheet. Only objects that are already linked to other objects will be linked objects on the new sheet. 
When copying objects I recommend to always paste using the right-mouse option and select "paste sheet object" or "paste sheet object as linked object".

Answer (score 2):

If you do not see the Unlink option, then this is not a linked object.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not see the "linked objects" part in the right-click menu. I recommend to go and check your security level in the document properties or sheet properties.

Note that there is actually no difference between QlikView version 11 or 12 regarding linked objects.

Answer (score 0):

Always you can "unlink" an object just changing the "Object ID" (Object properties > "General" tab) that identifies the object.
All linked objects share the same ID so is enough change the value of one of them to unlink this instance.